# In the bootstrap 4 navbar elements goes under others on small screen resolutions

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm novice of BootStrap (4) and i've this code:

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light justify-content-between">
            <a class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
            <form class="form-inline">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"  aria-describedby="SearchButton" id="Search">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="SearchButton"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button id="PagePrev" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></button>
                <button id="PageNext" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>
            </form>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

When the width is > 576 all goes well but on smaller widths the buttons goes down under the input. The question is: how can i treat all elements (input and buttons) as a unique block? I've tried the "form-inline" but, of course, i'm wrong. Any help is fine!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to include the `navbar-expand` class for the Navbar to remain horizontal at all screen widths. Also, add the `flex-nowrap` class to the `form-inline`...

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-light justify-content-between">
            <a class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
            <form class="form-inline flex-nowrap">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"  aria-describedby="SearchButton" id="Search">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="SearchButton"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button id="PagePrev" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></button>
                <button id="PageNext" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>
            </form>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/kzachp9MQ1